# SQL Server MERGE on a large table with small log file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a MERGE statement on a large table (5M of rows) with a small log file size (2GB).  I am getting an error:

> Merge for MyTable failed: The transaction log for database 'MyDb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

Could be this solved by another action than extending the log file? I can’t really afford to extend the log file currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed log file size, you have essentially two options:

1. Temporarily change the recovery mode of your database from FULL to BULK-LOGGED.  You'll lose the ability to do point-in-time recovery during this period, but it allows you to quickly do the operation and then go back.  There are other caveats, so you need to do some research to make sure this is what you want to do.
2. Instead of changing the transaction log, you can adopt a batching approach to commit small batches of changes at a time, thus allowing the log to flush as needed.

Comment: ad 1, will that help if I have currently set up the DB recovery mode to SIMPLE?

Comment: ad 2, I assume this means I have to rewrite the MERGE statement into something more complicated.

Comment: for ad 1, no, sorry; SIMPLE recovery is the most minimal amount of logging that you can do.  If db is already SIMPLE, then your only option is to optimize the MERGE.